# Why with the use of "new" keyword, the object created refers to the same object?

Tags: c#, static

These are my classes:

```
namespace MyFirstGame
{
    public static class OstacoliManager
    {
        #region Dichiarazioni

        private static List<Ostacolo> ostacoli = new List<Ostacolo>();
        private static List<Ostacolo> oggettiSulloSchermo = new List<Ostacolo>();
        private static int objectCount = 20;
        private static Random rand = new Random();

        #endregion

        #region Metodi ausiliari

        public static void Inizializza()
        {
            oggettiSulloSchermo.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)
            {
                //Dalla lista degli ostacoli ne creo tot a caso. Lo faccio da ostacoli e non da texture per l'eventualità in cui abbiano dimensioni diverse ecc
                int randIndex = rand.Next(0, ostacoli.Count());
                Ostacolo o = new Ostacolo(
                    ostacoli[randIndex].Texture,
                    ostacoli[randIndex].Strada,
                    ostacoli[randIndex].DrawDepth
                );

                o.resetPosition();
                oggettiSulloSchermo.Add(o);
            }
        }

        ...
```

The class "Ostacolo" is declared:

```
namespace MyFirstGame
{
    public class Ostacolo : GameObject
    {
        #region Dichiarazioni

        private Random rand = new Random();
        private Texture2D texture;

        #endregion

        #region Costruttore

        public Ostacolo(Texture2D texture, LayerDiSfondo strada, float profondita)
        {
           ...
        }

        #endregion
```

When, in the first block of code, I call the function "Inizializza()", in particular where I do:

```
   Ostacolo o = new Ostacolo(...)
```

and

```
   oggettiSulloSchermo.Add(o)

          public void resetPosition()
    {
        WorldLocation = new Vector2(rand.Next(600, 3000), strada.doveCamminareY());
    }
```

with

```
 private Random rand = new Random();
```

I discover that o refers everytime to the same object!
"New" keyword do create a new object, doens't it?

Comment: How are you checking that `o` actually refers to the same object?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about it.

Comment: how did yo discover that ?

Comment: What you mean `o` refers to the same object? You're creating a new object every loop.

Comment: Based only on this code, there is no way that `o` is the same object.

Comment: @tuttoscorre He asked "*how* are you checking", not "are you sure".

Comment: For 2 reasons: 1. This application is a game, and it should draw on the screen 20 "ostacolo" in at different locations, but it draws everyone at the same location 2. I debugged it and watched inside "oggettiSulloSchermo", and it every object inside has the same properties

Comment: ...because the **fields** inside each object are still referencing the same thing! Make sure to make a deep copy when you need one - sounds like `Strada` is of reference type? ;)

Comment: @tuttoscorre Well, you *are* calling `o.resetPosition()`, so I'd expect them to be in the same position.

Comment: `int randIndex = rand.Next(0, ostacoli.Count());` look at this what the value of `Count()`?

Comment: @olydis Yes but when I do "o.resetPosition()" it calculates a random location, every object should have a different location. But it doesn't!

Comment: In that case show the code for `resetPosition`. Also make the `Random` class in `Ostacolo` static.

Comment: 1. how do you calculate random (be careful about using new `Random` instances each time, they are likely to return the same values), 2. are you **overwriting** your fields in this method?

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria count in this case is 1 because to do some test I loaded only 1 "ostacolo" and only 1 texture. The problem is that o.restPosition() gives Always the same coordinates to every "new" object

Comment: @tuttoscorre Then you should have included that code as well. The culprit seems to be the fact that you're creating very fast many `Random` objects and they end up having the same seed.

Comment: Well show the code `o.restPosition()`.

Comment: @olydis private Random rand = new Random(); for the random number inside "o.ResetPosition()" is this the problem?

Comment: yes it is! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004929/randomnumber-method-returns-same-number-every-time-called

Comment: @tuttoscorre: Yes. Create your `Random` instance only once.

Comment: make it static and it will work ;) `Random` initializes itself using system time... as you might guess they are likely to be initialized identically since you create your objects in a little loop :D

Comment: LOL! Many many thanks, it works! How can I close question?

Comment: @tuttoscorre Wait for someone to post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I see the call to *o.resetPosition();* before adding to the list. What that method does do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `Random` within each instance of `Ostacolo`, that you will use within `restPosition` to "randomly" position each instance. Make this instance `static` to resolve the issue that arises:

`Random` uses system time to initialize itself internally - so when you create several instances within a short period of time (as in your case), they will propably all behave identically!

See this post for further info: [RandomNumber method returns same number every time called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004929/randomnumber-method-returns-same-number-every-time-called)